# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8

I am working on app second version update. Everything was working fine but suddenly I started getting this error. I am using GPUImage library for filtering. I am testing my app on iPhone 6/iOS 8.3. I also checked my old code but I started getting same error. Anybody help me to resolve this issue.

[image: Error in GPUImageFrameBuffer]

Comment: We're seeing the same now we're building with Xcode 7/iOS 9 SDK. We see no crash using the iOS 8 SDK with Xcode 6. Are you on Xcode 7 too? FWIW, an iPhone 5S and iPad 4 both on 8.2 work fine.

Comment: Yes, I am using Xcode7/iOS 9. You are right is no crash using the iOS 8 SDK with Xcode 6. But it only crash during debugging. In reality application runs fine on mobile after installation.

Comment: We should open a radar. I don't have a small reproducible case to do so with. Have you already opened a radar I can duplicate?

Comment: No. You can open it.

Comment: I created a small test case passing the same parameters as the crashing scenario, but of course it doesn't crash! There must be something else happening before that triggers it. I've not yet narrowed that down.

Comment: What I read is that the problem is related to GPU of device. Somehow, when you apply filter the image using Gaussian or some other filter, this error occurs. Actually, this error must not occur because in reality, everything is working fine. I think, there is bug in GPUImage library. This library needs to be updated according to iOS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had some code calling `CVPixelBufferCreate` that was passing bad parameters. AFAIK this came from some sample code, with some bad copy & pasting after, so perhaps yours has the same error.

`CVPixelBufferCreate` takes an attributes dictionary. Some of the keys, like `kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey` take a CFBoolean, but we were passing a dictionary. This style works:

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{ (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey : @{},
                         (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey: @YES}; <-- we had @{} !

err = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, formatType, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attrs, &pixelBuffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using GPUImage 1.6.0 and see the same issue. Tried to hack with the suggested proposal - but it didn't help. Any other ideas/suggestions?

```
CFDictionarySetValue(attrs, kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey, empty);
CFDictionarySetValue(attrs, kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey, kCFBooleanTrue);

CVReturn err = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (int)_size.width, (int)_size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, attrs, &renderTarget);
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this solution from Brad Larsen and I think he is right.
"If you're doing filtering directly from the camera, don't use -imageByFilteringImage: and intermediary UIImages. This will be horribly expensive, both in memory consumption and performance, because you have to convert to and from UIImages on the CPU. Instead, chain filters from a GPUImageVideoCamera instance."